# Behaviour regarding db pool and connection.setReadOnly() method

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, database-replication, c3p0

I have Java application with Hibernate framework(no spring) connect to MySQL DB , manage connection pooling via c3p0

i try to configure my apllication to read from slave db and write to master db , i have following this link to some extend [Master/Slave load balance](http://www.dragishak.com/?p=307)

let's say if the application already got a session with connection in pool and it need to execute a read-only method , like this

```
public someReadOnlyMethod()
{
    Session session = (get session from current Thread)

            //set read-only so that it read from slave db
            session.connection().setReadOnly(true);

            (...connect to db to do something...)

            //set it back in case of this method is followed by write method so that it go to master db
            session.connection().setReadOnly(false);


}
```

Is the pooling create a new connection to connect to db 2 times for read-only and write operation(if so,this will heavily impact performance) or it smart enough to swap the operation to already existing read-only and writable connection pool ?

thx for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

so this has nothing to do with the pool; it's all in the mysql driver. c3p0 will pass your call to setReadOnly (whether true or false) to the underlying Connection, and the Connection will route to the master or the slaves accordingly.

if you don't like how your Connections default (probably by default they are not read only), you can set the read-only property in the onAcquire method of a c3p0 ConnectionCustomizer, and the value use set (true or false) will become th default that c3p0 resets Connections to.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: It will re-use existing connections whenever you switch `setReadOnly(true/false)`.

JDBC will connect to all servers listed in your connection URL when you do `ReplicationDriver().connect(url)`. Those connections will remain open for re-use no matter how many times you switch `setReadOnly()`.

Source: I just tested Connector/J version 5.1.38 with `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver`.